# Learn about users without blowing up server?

Tags: mysql, web-applications

I'm building a network of services, and all the services are completely different from one another, and now I'm creating a dashboard to make the experience easier to work with, creating an automatic list of the services the user uses most.

But if I want to find out which products the users use the most, how would I do that without causing heavy overload on the server? By that, I mean whenever a user goes to a page on that service, ie http://foo.com/bar/nyancattastic2.php I would find the keyword (app name) being 'bar', and then add a hit, by updating the row where the username is matched to 'bar' in my database with hits=hits+1

Although, putting that on every page would really destroy my server with an update query on every page.

Any ideas? Alternatively, I could ask the user what their favorite apps are, but that's more a UX question.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Karan

**Edit* The levels of traffic I expect are around 3-10 Queries/Second without this suggested change!**

Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: I would think one update statement is probably not going to cause the world to explode.  If your services do anything of any consequence they are already doing much more than a single update.

Comment: Is your load really so high already and your traffic so heavy that the addition of an `INSERT` would bog your server? And if you did it only temporarily? And what if you randomly sampled users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on your load, if there are several queries per seconds, it can become a problem because when you do an update field = field + 1, you do an implicit lock on the field.

If you do have that level of traffic, you can consider instead to write a line to a log file and post process it, or add a line to a mysql table, that will get periodically aggregated.  Another idea is parse the webserver logs.

I personally got bitten by this update field + 1, when I tried to use it on a heavy traffic national soccer website, so yes, it can become a problem, but only at high levels of traffic.

Also check out the idea of Michael, to randomly sample users in case the load is really too high. With 3-5 queries per second you don't have to worry, of course it depends on the server, but problems are likely to happen around hundred queries per second.

Comment: A better way to go would be Running the query on documentload, no? As it would let the page load first, not locking the page, but yeah, I guess it would still lock the field :\ The level of traffic right now is expected to be around 3-10 queries per second, probably going to increase to 20-30 in a month or two. I will probably have to go with log parsing when it does reach that point :S Thanks for your answer and experience with a similar problem! :)

Comment: yes, using AJAX will surely mitigate the problem, if you'll reach that point however, aside from a log file, you can also consider to still use MySQL for logging, with an INSERT DELAYED (one row per call), and then run a process every X minutes that would compact those values in another table. To avoid locking the DB with an expensive compacting, you can limit compacting of Y rows per time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really concerned about the traffic and load (I wouldn't be concerned until I saw a problem), you could consider randomly sampling users:

```
// Check about 1/5 users:
$random_thresh = 5;

if (rand() % $random_thresh == 0) {
  // Log an insert for this user:
}
```

Comment: If he's only interested to find the most popular services and not the exact numbers sounds like a good idea, and also absolute numbers can be estimated anyway +1.

Comment: This is quite a clever solution, but the problem is that I need to learn about every user, giving each user their 'most used apps'. The load I'm expecting is anywhere between 3-10 queries per second. Thanks alot for your answer! Will definitely use it for surveying in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't answer your question directly, but coming from another angle.

It might be possible to use Google Analytics to track the data and then use the analytics API to get the information you require.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/

Comment: I was thinking about that, but examining the XML data would be more of a CRON job than a live update of the data, and it might just be a little fiddly, although it is a good idea, and I will consider it when I will probably fail! haha, Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: No worries @Karan it sounds like an interesting project, good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're dealing with huge traffic levels and constant high server load, I don't think you need worry too much about overtaxing your servers with a tiny command like that.

Comment: +1 to this. Updating a single entry in MySQL is extremely fast. Just ensure that this update is done in a non-blocking way from your web server (that is, you don't wait for a response from the MySQL server before serving the page to the user).

Comment: @TrevorBurnham A better way would be with Ajax on document load, no? Thanks for that :D

Comment: @JHolyhead my server's pretty weak already adding on the 3-10 expected queries per second! D: Thanks for your answer :)